# Measuring request response time by port

Tags: iptables, performance, http, port, time

So, I'm currently working on a project in which I spin up a set docker image on a number of different machines and configurations. This image basically contains a web server that accepts a number of different, but similar requests to a single port. For this situation, it would be great to measure the typical response time of a specific port across the types of requests.

Ideally, I would be able to do this without editing the source of the web server, as the specific server could change. Is there a way for me to directly measure time between a request coming in on a port and the response that is ultimately returned by the machine?

I was looking for generalized interfaces to incoming packets, but I couldn't find any tools other than `iptables`, which didn't really seem to be the right tool.

I feel like this relatively simple level of analytics should be pretty easy to achieve and there must be some tool that achieves this, but I haven't found anything yet. If I looked through the code of `iptables` I'm sure I could implement something in pure C, but I can't help but think there's a better way to do this.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: tcpdump comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Apache already has this built in.

```
%D The time taken to serve the request, in microseconds.
```

There are more aspects of timing covered in Apache's **[mod_log_format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html)** page.

There are a few other options on that page you could use together to get very accurate calculations.

Comment: I don't use apache... I was really hoping for something more on the Linux side. Tcpdump actually looks basically like what I want